# Return object into different variables in google tag manager

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

There is a problem from my side

In a custom javascript function in google tag manager, which extract the UTM parameter, and let's call it **adServer**, I got an returned object which looks like the followings everytime when the script is triggered:

```
{lng: "en", version: "2.3", os: "win", tab: "1", utm_campaign: "promotion101"}
{lng: "en", version: "2.4", os: "mac", tab: "1", utm_campaign: "promotion101"}
{lng: "en", version: "2.4", os: "mac", tab: "1", utm_campaign: "promotion101"}
```

---

So what I want to do is, break down the objects into strings and save into different variables, so that I can analyse the certain properties in google analytics e.g how many ppl is visiting with os 'win' or 'app'. And everytime when there is a visitor, the os and the languaage variable can be extracted.

---

To do so, I tried to set up an custom variable in google tag manager, let's called adsOS, to extract the information from **adServer** with the script

```
function() {
  var OS = {{adServer}}.os
  return OS
}
```

And another custom variable called adsLanguage

```
function() {
  var language = {{adServer}}.lng
  return language
}
```

Unfortunately it does not work. 
Is there any alternative method, that I can extract part of the object in a custom variable and copy it to another custom variable in google tag manager?

Many thanks for your help

Comment: Did you used the dot notation to store the variable? `{“adsOs.lng”:”value”}`. You can retrieve the value like so `{{ adsOs.lng }}`

Comment: Can you show the definiton of your variables? Because what you are trying to do is possible and should work as you define, but I'm not sure if is there any reference error or something.